# Exposing the IfcPresentationLayerAssignment from an Ifc file using Python

Tags: python, ifc, fme

I need to expose the IfcPresentationLayerAssignment entity from my IFC file where autocad layer information is stored.

I need to do this in FME, however FME currently doesn't have the capability to expose this information even though I see the IfcPresentationLayerAssignment entity is in the file by reading it as plain text.

I am wondering whether I can extract this information using python and then append this back into the model as a standard attribute?

Any help or guidance is appreciated

I haven't tried anything yet as I don't fully understand the breakdown of an IFC file, but thought I would ask to see if something like this is possible